# Click on 1 cell, populate that data in another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a google sheet where I can click on 1 cell in A5 and it will put that information into another cell. I dont know if it matters but in my actual google sheet the cell that would get auto populated on click would then be used to generate a pie chart based on data pulled from the web.

[image: example]

Comment: Hi I posted my answer. Let me know if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

To create an `onClick` event you can use [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee).

The following script will:

- execute a particular block of code, when a
  cell in column **A** and `row > 1` (excluding `A1`) is **clicked /
  selected**.

In more detail, it will **populate** the value of the cell you selected in column **A** to the cell `C2`.

---

### Solution:

To enable the process, just **copy** & **paste** the following code snippet to the script editor and click **save**.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) { 

  const cell = e.range;
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();  
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 1 && row > 1 ) {  
    as.getRange('C2').setValue(cell.getValue());  
  }
}
```

Please modify the name `Sheet1` to your particular sheet name of interest.

Comment: TY for the response. Will this still allow the script to run if scripts elsewhere run when C2 is populated?

Comment: Great, last thing. There seems to be a 2-3 second delay when I click on a cell in column A to it being populated in column C is that normal?

Comment: @arkad yes it is normal. It is just a Google service drawback. Consider accepting the answer and voting up if it worked for you. :)

Comment: Marios, is there a way to make this work but the data that is pulled be from a different column than column A? Such as click on A2, grab data from B2 and use that data in C2?

Comment: replace `cell.getValue()` with `as.getRange('B2').getValue()` @arkad